# Difference between MySQL .zip and .msi download

Tags: mysql, installation, windows-installer

Sorry I know this is not really a programming question.

But when for example on the MySQL website you are given the option to download a .zip or .msi file. Is the result exactly the same application, or do the two work slightly different. I.e. the .zip option being more self contained, with everything under the MySQL folder and nothing in the registry etc.

This will help a lot towards my problem and future problems.

Comment: vote for close / belongs on serverfault. Hopefully that will trigger an automatic move?

Comment: ServerFault is in beta, you need to be invited to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if I plan to have single MySQL installation on single box - I use .msi

With multiple installations on single box .zip packges are easier to handle.

Comment: Also with zip you don't needs to have admin privileges to start server (Firewall may still need to be tweaked though by Admin).

Answer (score 4):

If you follow the links from the download page you can find [an answer to this on the MySQL website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-choosing-package.html).